# What happens when the system purges an app while in background?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I know my app can be killed while in background by the system.

Is it also possible to have its data structures released but the app not being killed?

- I use to save user data in `-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:`.
- I always restore that data in `-(BOOL)application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Should I also restore local data in `-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:`?

If the app is killed it will come back through `-(BOOL)application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` so my data will be restored, but if it is not killed but its data structures released it will came back through `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:` so no data will be restored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is killed and then relaunched your `-application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` will be called.

If your app is backgrounded and then resumed `-applicationWillEnterForeground:` will be called.

You should not need to restore data state when `-applicationWillEnterForeground:` is called.